# Responsive images, browsers, and network speed?

Tags: html, image, browser

I have an image that at the moment is only one size (`600px x 300px`), and I use CSS to make sure it responds to viewport widths. Under `600px` it's width is `100%`, over `600px` it's fixed at `600px`.

I now want to use:

```
<img src="" srcset="" sizes="" />
```

...to implement responsive images with the hope that mobile users can download smaller file-size images.

Very quickly I've run into the "small screen vs network speed" issue.

I can make multiple image sizes available, but the pixel density on some mobiles means that sometimes a mobile would request a much larger image than a desktop. I have two internet connected devices in front of me:

1. Windows desktop, widescreen monitor, very fast network connection, pixel density x1.
2. iPhone X, 3G connection, `375px` viewport, pixel density x3.

Using `srcset` and `sizes` would mean the desktop downloads a `600px` image, and the iPhone downloads a `1125px` (`375 * 3`) image.

Question:

Do browsers take network speed into account (would my iPhone on a slow 3G connection select a smaller image from `srcset`, or would it always us `1125px`)..?

I've searched online for an answer, I can't find anything, I'm happy to be pointed in the right direction from a link.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is yet possible. However, there's a proposal (draft) for a [Network Information API from the W3C](http://wicg.github.io/netinfo/) that is designed to provide a way for scripts to be notified if the connection changes (cellular, WiFi, ethernet, etc).

In the meantime perhaps you can use [lazy-loading](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/lazy-loading-guidance/images-and-video/) to load image resources on demand. Doesn't really solve the problem you're describing, but it does alleviate initial network load on from web applications on devices.

**Update**: Ok, so according to [Pete LePage](https://twitter.com/petele), this is not yet possible:

> [Last I heard, it does not. It's not out of the question for the future, check http://crbug.com  for a feature request, and if there isn't one, file it!](https://twitter.com/petele/status/1063672665360269312)

Comment: Thanks Juan! I'm already lazy loading (with [lazysizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes)). I hadn't seen that draft proposal, thank you. My question more relates to, when the *browser* is deciding which `srcset` image to use, whether it takes network speed into account, or only the logic from `sizes`.

Comment: @StephenLast Perhaps you can reach out to either [Pete LePage](https://twitter.com/petele) or [Ilya Grigorik](https://twitter.com/igrigorik) both are developer advocates for Google's Web Team. Pete has many articles describing how to use the `srcset` attribute. Perhaps they might know if this is possible or not.